# capture a url from angularJS in a windows open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm having a little trouble with a window.

I have to make a windows.open.so far everything very well and without problems, the detail is that this new window is a login that redirects me when I login and I must capture the new url at that time.

my question is, is it possible to make a variable that listens to this new window? and whenever I detect a change in the url I save the whole url?

the process is

http://localhost:8520/pasar -> http://localhost:8520/login?blahblahblah -> http://finalURLWithParams.com/&hi=123&code=456

after logging in and all I have to do is capture code. Is it possible to do this?

```
      $scope.rowAuthJSONConnect = function () {
            console.warn("Entrando a rowAuthJSONConnect");
            console.warn("URL:");
            console.log(vm.URLRowAuthJson);

            var windowOpen = window.open('http://localhost:8520/pasar', "RedsysOpen", "width=900,height=600");

            console.log(windowOpen);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the child window update the URL in parent window by calling a setter method in parent window, like below,

```
    // define this method in main window (angular controller )
    window.setNewUrl = function(result) {
        console.log("new URL is : " + result);
    }

    //define the function below in the child window (the window that you opened with window.open)

    function sendUrlToParent() {
      try {
            window.opener.setNewUrl("new url here");
      } catch(e) {
            console.log("Exception setting value in parent " + e);
      }
    }
```

If you want to update any angular variable inside the setNewUrl method, I think you need to call $scope.$apply in the end.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed.